# Como retornar pontos dentro de um raio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geometria, geolocalização

Estou elaborando um app onde precisaria retornar pontos (Lat, Long) num raio de tamanho X (Km)  a partir da localização do usuário(Lat, Long). Idealizei a seguinte lógica:

- Pegar a localização atual do user
- Inserir a localização do user como a ponta A do raio, e a distância desse raio como a ponta B, em latitude e longitude.

  Porém estou em dificuldade em determinar como calcular e converter essa distância para metros ou quilômetros.

  Os pontos que serão buscados estão armazenados no app, não necessitando de requisições de um webservice.

  No final irei listar em um array os pontos que estão dentro do raio.

  Alguém conhece uma API ou métodos que possam ajudar a elaborar esta função.

  OBS: Estou usando a API google maps iOS para mostrar o mapa, estou armazenando os pontos dos locais que serão buscados dentro do raio no próprio App. Estou usando as coordenadas do Google Maps.

Imagem para Ilustrar: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando diz que tem os pontos guardados na app está a referir-se a uma BD?

Comment: Sim, os locais estão armazenado usando coredata e inclui nome e coordenadas (latitude, longetude).

Comment: Eu tive uma idéia para resolver este problema, porém ela retornou outra questão.

 Possível resposta: 

Envio as coordenadas para CCLocation, e pego a distância, e faço a seguinte comparação:

`if(distancia < X){ // Dentro do Raio, slavo no array}`

Porém este conceito vai forçar o app a percorrer TODOS os pontos armazenados. 

 Para resolver este problema então pensei em implementar algo usando uma árvore binária de busca (Me corrijam se eu estiver engano com o nome), mas nunca implementei uma antes.

Comment: Suponho que consegue filtar esses dados por latitude/longitude ou não? Desculpe a pergunta o meu conhecimento sobe IOS/ObjectiveC é quase null.

Comment: Tranquilo! :D Acredito que vc ja tenha ouvido falar de Arvore Binária. Se sim iria ajudar muito.

Comment: Vou dar uma resposta veja se serve.

Comment: @ramaral obrigado "irmão"! Pelo nome já temos algum grau de parentesco kkkk Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o seu problema consiste em determinar se um um par de coordenadas pertence a uma região circular então eu sugiro utilizar o seguinte código, assumindo um raio de 1km:

```
CLLocation *posicaoAtual = <Posicao retornada pelo CoreLocation>;

CLCircularRegion *areaCircular  = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:posicaoAtual.coordinate radius:1000 identifier:@"MyID"];

CLLocation *outraPosicao = <Posicao que você quer testar se está dentro da região>;
if (areaCircular containsCoordinate:outraPosicao.coordinate])
    NSLog("Está dentro da região");
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquilo que pode fazer é, em vez de encontrar os pontos que esteja dentro de um circulo, é encontrar os pontos que estejam dentro de um quadro que tem esse circulo inscrito.
Um quadro cujos lado é igual ao dobro do raio estando no seu centro a localização do usuário.

A GoogleMaps api para android tem uma classe com vários métodos que permitem fazer alguns cálculos com pontos definidos como Lat/Long permitindo calcular, nomeadamente, outro ponto a uma determinada distância do primeiro segundo uma direção.

Julgo que essa classe não existe na API google maps iOS mas encontrei no [GitHub](https://github.com/carmichaelalonso/SphericalUtils-iOS/blob/master/SphericalUtil.m) uma alternativa.

A solução que eu sugiro é que se calcule os pontos que ficam da localização do usuário à distância *raio* nas direções (A)0º, (B)90º, (C)180º e (D)270º
Para isso utilize a função `computeOffsetWithLatitude`

Os pontos(P) que estão dentro do quadrado serão aqueles cuja Lat/Long tornam a seguinte expressão verdadeira:

```
P.Lat <= A.Lat && P.Lat >= C.Lat && P.Long <= B.Lon && P.Long >= D.Long
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz isso em um projeto aonde eu usava a distancia entre dois pontos ma levando em consideração a curvatura da terra, em pequenas distancias não vejo problema, mas em distancias maiores esse erro é gradualmente maior.

```
 public double distaincia(double latInicial, double latFinal, double lngInicial, double lngFinal) {
    double distancia = 6378140 * Math.acos(Math.cos(Math.PI * (90 - latFinal) / 180) * Math.cos((90 - latInicial) * Math.PI / 180)
            + Math.sin((90 - latFinal) * Math.PI / 180) * Math.sin((90 - latInicial) * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos((lngInicial - lngFinal) * Math.PI / 180));
    return distancia;
}
```

isso me retorna a distancia entre dois pontos em metros, então se definir um raio de 30KM é so fazer a verificação desta distancia.