# Geolocalização Por Raio de Kilometragem a Partir de um Ponto Central

Tags: javascript, html, geolocalização

Estou procurando como fazer um script de Geolocalização para encontrar cidades num raio de **X Km** a partir de um ponto central.

Como assim ?

Por exemplo, em um combobox escolho uma cidade - Rio Claro/SP - daí a partir dessa cidade eu quero selecionar algumas cidades num raio de 50Km, 100Km e assim por diante.

Essa escolha de KM também seria um combobox para opção do usuário.

Eu não tenho nenhum script porquê nunca fiz isso. Na verdade preciso de links instrutivos e uma base para começar a entender.

A cidade principal a ser escolhida viria do banco de dados, que preencherá um combobox. E as outras cidades também estariam no banco de dados.

Comment: Agora não tem mais graça meu avatar porquê já descobriram minha identidade... parcialmente.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34959/como-buscar-por-dist%c3%a2ncia http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9128/como-obter-dist%c3%a2ncia-dadas-as-coordenadas-usando-sql http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70447/como-calcular-a-dist%c3%a2ncia-entre-dois-pontos-de-localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64260/gostaria-de-achar-a-distancia-em-km-entre-dois-markers-como-posso-fazer http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82585/google-maps-mostrar-markers-dentro-de-certa-distancia http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57987/como-retornar-pontos-dentro-de-um-raio

Comment: @Bacco, sou bem leigo nesse assunto. Abaixo de leigo ainda. Não entendi muita coisa, quase nada, desses links.

Comment: pra ser mais específico que esses links, seria legal vc complementar a pergunta dizendo de onde vem esses dados (se é um DB, por exemplo), em que formato estão, etc. Para alguém explicar como aplicar o conceito mais adequado na prática, só sabendo o contexto todo. Lembrando que dependendo do caso, tem DBs especializados nisso.

Comment: Entendi. Vou especificar